# Why is my delete function resulting in an undefined value error?

Tags: node.js, reactjs

I'm building app using ReactJs and NodeJs. App is displaying data from database or all rooms. Room have to be abled to be created, edited and deleted.

Create and edit is working. The delete function is not.

Here is code:

**Rooms.js**

```
export default class RoomsAdmin extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = { rooms: [] };
        this.delete = this.delete.bind(this);
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        axios.get('http://localhost:3090/admin/')
            .then(response => {
                this.setState({ rooms: response.data });
            })
            .catch(function (error){
                console.log(error);
            })
    }

    componentDidUpdate() {
        axios.get('http://localhost:3090/admin/')
            .then(response => {
                this.setState({ rooms: response.data });
            })
            .catch(function (error){
                console.log(error);
            })
    }

    delete() {
        axios.get('http://localhost:3090/admin/delete/'+this.props.room._id)
            .then(console.log('Deleted'))
            .catch(err => console.log(err))
    }


 roomList() {
   const Room = props => (
      <div className="col-md-4">
       <div className="card mb-4 shadow-sm">
        <div className="card-body">
         <h5 class="card-title">{props.room.title}</h5>
          <p className="card-text">{props.room.description}</p>
           <div className="d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center">
           <div className="btn-group">
            <Link className="btn btn-sm btn-outline-secondary" 
            to={ "/edit/"+props.room._id}>Edit</Link>
          <button onClick={this.delete}>Delete</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

        )

        return this.state.rooms.map(function (currentRoom, i) {
            return <Room room={currentRoom} key={i} />
        });
    }

    render() {
        return (

            <div>
                <Header />
                <div>
                    <div className="album py-5 bg-light">
                        <div className="container">
                            <div className="row">
                                {this.roomList()}
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        )
    }

}
```

After clicking on delete I get this error:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '_id' of undefined

Any tip would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are confusing a parent -> child relationship here. There is only one component, so you don't have `props.room`. Instead just pass the room id to be deleted in the callback function.

```
<button onClick={this.delete.bind(null, props.room._id}>Delete</button>
```

and your handler function

```
delete(id) {
```

I would rename your handler to be a little more explicit, also `delete` is a keyword in javascript so probably best to avoid that function name.

```
deleteRoom(id) {
    axios.get(`http://localhost:3090/admin/delete/${id}`)
        .then(console.log('Deleted'))
        .catch(err => console.log(err))
```

---

Edit, I cleaned up the code a little, moved the child component outside of the parent so you dont need to reinitialize that component each time you render.

```
export default class RoomsAdmin extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = { rooms: [] }
    this.deleteRoom = this.deleteRoom.bind(this)
  }
  componentDidMount() {
    axios.get('http://localhost:3090/admin/')
      .then(response => {
        this.setState({ rooms: response.data })
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.log(error)
      })
  }

  componentDidUpdate() {
    axios.get('http://localhost:3090/admin/')
      .then(response => {
        this.setState({ rooms: response.data })
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.log(error)
      })
  }

  deleteRoom(id) {
    axios.get(`http://localhost:3090/admin/delete/${id}`)
      .then(console.log('Deleted'))
      .catch(err => console.log(err))
  }

  roomList() {
    return this.state.rooms.map((currentRoom, i) => (
      <Room 
        room={currentRoom}
        onDelete={this.deleteRoom.bind(null, currentRoom._id)}
        key={i}
      />
    ))
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <Header />
        <div>
          <div className="album py-5 bg-light">
            <div className="container">
              <div className="row">{this.roomList()}</div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    )
  }
}

const Room = props => (
  <div className="col-md-4">
    <div className="card mb-4 shadow-sm">
      <div className="card-body">
        <h5 class="card-title">{props.room.title}</h5>
        <p className="card-text">{props.room.description}</p>
        <div className="d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center">
          <div className="btn-group">
            <Link
              className="btn btn-sm btn-outline-secondary"
              to={`/edit/${props.room._id}`}
            >
              Edit
            </Link>
            <button onClick={props.onDelete}>Delete</button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
)
```

Comment: I have tried you code and I am getting following error `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'props' of null`

Comment: Which line is that happening on?

Comment: On onClick={this.delete.bind(null, props.room._id} line

Comment: and you put that click handler on the button in the `const Room = props => (` component?

Comment: It is outside should I put it in?

Comment: Yes it should be in the `Room` component. Replace your button element with the one in my answer. Yes, you are telling each room element when you click delete this is the item / id to use to delete. It needs to be on a room by room (element by element) basis.

Comment: here ill update my answer with the whole component :)

Comment: That would be very helpful! Thank you!

Comment: @user9347049 see my latest update, I moved the `Room` component outside of the parent as an optimization and cleaned up the code a little (arrow functions.. etc). The meat of what should happen is there though incase you dont want to keep those changes :)

Comment: Thank you for your time and effort! Code works perfect! :)